# To add a symbol after a label

Tags: enumitem

How would I add `:` after a description list's labels? In this case this means having `Foo:` rather than `Foo` (and the same for `Bar').

PS: Also, what would be the settings for an `itemize` list that turn it into a `description` list?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{description}{1}
\setlist[mylist]
{align=left,
  leftmargin=0pt%,
%afterlabel={:}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
\item[Foo] \lipsum[1]
\item[Bar] \lipsum[2]
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a specific macro that sets the "font" of the label in `mylist`. That is, use `font=<commands>`, since the [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) mentions

> The last command in `<commands>` can take an argument with the item label.

This "font" macro takes 1 argument - the optional argument supplied by `\item` - which allows you to negotiate around it with additional content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mylistlabelfont}[1]{{\bfseries #1:}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{description}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{%
  align=left,
  leftmargin=0pt,
  font=\mylistlabelfont
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
  \item[Foo] \lipsum[1]
  \item[Bar] \lipsum[2]
  \item[Foo bar] \lipsum[3]
\end{mylist}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution to modify only the `mylist` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{description}{1}
\setlist[mylist]
{align=left,
  leftmargin=0pt}

\AtBeginEnvironment{mylist}{\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \hspace\labelsep
  \normalfont\bfseries#1:}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
\item[Foo] \lipsum[1]
\item[Bar] \lipsum[2]
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution by redefining `descriptionlabel`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{description}{1}
\setlist[mylist]
{align=left,
  leftmargin=0pt
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \hspace\labelsep \upshape\bfseries #1:%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mylist}
\item[Foo] \lipsum[1]
\item[Bar] \lipsum[2]
\end{mylist}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice, but what if I have more than one description list?